# Pinging servers from txt source to list Pingtimes

Tags: batch-file, ping

I have got this script from stackoverflow for pinging multiple addresses from a .txt source (testservers.txt) to output to another .txt file (result.txt)

```
    @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTPUT_FILE=result.txt
>nul copy nul %OUTPUT_FILE%
for /f %%i in (testservers.txt) do (
    set SERVER_ADDRESS=ADDRESS N/A
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%x in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^&^& echo SERVER_IS_UP') do (
        if %%x==Pinging set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%y
        if %%x==Reply set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%z
        if %%x==SERVER_IS_UP (set SERVER_STATE=UP) else (set SERVER_STATE=DOWN)
    )
    echo %%i [!SERVER_ADDRESS::=!] is !SERVER_STATE! >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
)
```

It only lists the server state, What modifications should I make if I want it to show the average ping time also?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This script takes the remote host as the first (and only) argument.
The number of samples (_COUNT) is hardcoded in, but configurable.
The three DEBUG lines are there just to check the results. They can be removed once you're confident that it produces correct output.

I don't know if ping ever reports time in something other than milliseconds. If it does, some account of that will need to be taken in the substitutions (and the units saved in a variable, probably).

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET _HOST=google.com
IF NOT "%~1"=="" SET "_HOST=%~1"

:: number of ICMP echo attempts (for a better average)
SET _COUNT=10

SET _SUM=0
SET _DEBUG=
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%l IN ('ping -n %_COUNT% %_HOST%') DO (
    FOR /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%t IN ("%%~l") DO (
        IF "%%~t"=="time" (
            SET _TIME=%%u
            SET _DEBUG=!_DEBUG! %%u
            SET _TIME=!_TIME:^<=!
            SET /A _SUM = !_SUM! + !_TIME:ms=!
        )
    )
)
SET /A _AVG = %_SUM% / %_COUNT%

@ECHO Average ping time for %_HOST%: %_AVG% ms
@ECHO DEBUG: %_DEBUG%
```